# How to fix SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, laravel, rest, api, ionic3

Want to display image, response from the rest API with Laravel in the view of ionic page.

Code worked when tested with postman, but in ionic gets error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ...

with HTTP status 200

Using JWT

backend :

```
public function maPhotoApi(Request $request){
    $user =  auth()->user();
    $residentModel = new Resident();
    $resident = $residentModel->getResidentByIdUser($user->id);

    if (is_dir(base_path('resources/resident/' . $resident->id_resident . '/')) && file_exists(base_path('resources/resident/' . $resident->id_resident . '/') . 'photo.jpg')) {
        $img = file_get_contents(base_path('resources/resident/' . $resident->id_resident . '/') . 'photo.jpg');
        return response($img)->header('Content-type', 'image/jpeg');
    } else {
        $img = file_get_contents(base_path('resources/resident/profil.png'));
        return response($img)->header('Content-type', 'image/jpeg');
    }
}
```

Frent-end(ionic) in the service or provider

```
maPhoto(){
  let httpOpt = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('token'),
      'Content-type': 'image/jpeg',
    })
  };
  return this.http.get(this.url + "maPhoto", httpOpt);

}
```

Component :

```
this.residentProvider.maPhoto().subscribe(data => {
  console.log("--------------------");
  console.log("photo => " , data);
  this.maPhoto = data;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

- The reason for this error is server is returning **plain text** or **HTML content** as the response and ionic app trying to parse to JSON. Server needs to send `data` as JSON.
- To confirm actually what Ionic app is getting from server, open google chrome developer tools and navigate to Network tab and select related api call and see Response tab. Ionic app should receive something like below.

[image]